# How to rename mutliples columns names (with prefix) according to respective dataframe name [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, multiple-join-rows

I have 15 dataframes, that I have merged together. [image: 15 dataframe]

1. Here I'm loading my files.

```
data_files <- list.files()  # Identify file names
                       

for(i in 1:length(data_files)) {                              
  assign(paste0(substr(data_files[i],1,nchar(data_files[i])-4)),             
           read_excel(paste0("",
                           data_files[i])))
}
```

Problem, they have the same columns names. That's why i want to rename the columns with the following code :

```
colnames(COMMUNITY)
 [1] "OBJECTID"                   "SOURCE_ID"                  "mean"                       "LMiIndex Fixed 450000 RS"  
 [5] "LMiZScore Fixed 450000 RS"  "LMiPValue Fixed 450000 RS"  "COType Fixed 450000 RS"     "NNeighbors Fixed 450000 RS"
 [9] "ZTransform Fixed 450000 RS" "SpatialLag Fixed 450000 RS"

colnames(COMMUNITY) <-paste("PREFIX",colnames(COMMUNITY),sep="-")
```

I would like to do this to my 15 dataframes, so I tried this :

```
List_df_EU = list(COMMUNITY,CSR_STRATEGY, EMISSIONS,ENV_PILLAR,ESGCOMBINED,ESGCONTROVERSIES,
                  ESGSCORE,GOV_PILLAR,HUMANRIGHTS,INNOVATION,MANAGEMENT,PRODUCT_RESP, RESSOURCE_USE, SOC_PILLAR, WORKFORCE)


for(i in 1:length(List_df_EU)) {                              
  colnames(List_df_EU[i]) <-paste("AS",colnames(List_df_EU[i]),sep="_")
  
}
```

It doesn't work, and, **I don't know how to retrieve dataframe name, in order to put him as PREFIX of columns.**
I could do it for each dataframe seperately, but it would take a long time, and would not be very clever.
Even after many web researches, I never found something that was automated.

After that, I use the following line of code to merge, It actually works, but as expected every colnames are identical.

```
Merged_file <- purrr::reduce(List_df_EU, dplyr::left_join, by = 'OBJECTID', suffix = c(".x", ".y"))
```

Comment: We have no sample data to work with, so there's a bit more inference and less likelihood that you'll get a great answer (quickly). It would help immensely if you reduced this from a problem with 15 frames and umpteen columns to just 3 small frames, perhaps a few rows each, and just enough columns in each that we get the point. The show what you want the output to be. Once you figure it out for 2-3 frames, expanding to 15 should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, refer to elements of the list with double square brackets, like so `List_df_EU[[i]]` (`List_df_EU[i]` is a sub-list of 1 element, not the element itself).

Second, we could create `List_df_EU` with `tibble::lst()` instead of `list()`, so that elements are automatically named. Then, `"AS"` can be replaced with `names(List_df_EU)[i]`.

```
List_df_EU <- tibble::lst(....)

for(i in 1:length(List_df_EU)) {                              
  colnames(List_df_EU[[i]]) <- paste(
    names(List_df_EU)[i], colnames(List_df_EU[[i]]), sep = "_")
}
```

---

*Edit*
To allow the subsequent join on `OBJECTID`, we could rename all columns but `OBJECTID`, for instance using `dplyr` that has a nice interface for this:

```
for(i in 1:length(List_df_EU)) {                              
  List_df_EU[[i]] <- dplyr::rename_with(
    List_df_EU[[i]],
    ~ paste(names(List_df_EU)[i], .x, sep = "_"),
    .cols = - OBJECTID
  )
}
```

Comment: Hello it works perfectly fine, so thank you.     
I'm just a little bit confused, because obviously `Merged_file <- purrr::reduce(List_df_EU, dplyr::left_join, by = "OBJECTID", suffix = c(".x", ".y"))` doens't work since `OBJECTID` does not exist anymore. ` Warning message:   
Unknown or uninitialised column: `OBJECTID`. `   
What should be the expression calling for each `OBJECTID` in each datafram of the list `List_df_EU` ?    I tried something like `colnames(List_df_EU[[i]])` but cant figure out how to get an array of each OBJECTID, or figure out a kind of regular expression.

Comment: Sorry I had missed that part. See my edit.

Comment: Ok thats great ! It makes it so much easier not to rename that column. Well thank you for your help. I had a bad time trying to join dataframes  with renamed OBJECTID.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest may be to bring them all into the same columns but add a column that indicates what file they came from. You could also `pivot_wider` and separate them again, at that point.

This function is for filling in the column that will be used to identify the source file.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
add_name <- function(flnm) {
  fread(flmn) %>%
  mutate(filename = basename(flmn))
}
```

Use this to collect the files and build the data frame.

```
mergedDF <- list.files(urlOrObject) %>%
  map_df(~add_name(.))
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Name your list, then you can get the name prefix:

   List_df_EU = list(COMMUNITY = COMMUNITY,CSR_STRATEGY = CSR_STRATEGY ...)
2. to set the colnames there is a [] missing:

   colnames(List_df_EU[[i]]) <- ...